# iPhone how to get the title for a custom Back-Button

Tags: iphone, back-button

Heyho,
I'm building a custom green back button
which is being created in the "viewDidAppear:" method.

I don't have any problems with the "getting-it-into-the-Navigationbar" or with "popping-the-current-View",
but my Problem is:

How do I get the title of the previous controller, so I can set it as Lable for the custom Back Button?
And is there a way to know if there even is any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The title of the back button is always the title of the 2nd top view controller.

Thus you can use (after ensuring there are ≥2 view controllers):

```
NSArray* viewCtrlers = self.navigationController.viewControllers;
UIViewController* prevCtrler = [viewCtrlers objectAtIndex:[viewCtrlers count]-2];
return prevCtrler.title;
```

---

If you're going for a green button, why not simply set the nav bar's tint to green?

Comment: because we want barbuttons with a different color, than the navigationbar ;)

Answer (score 1):

This is handled for you automatically.  Just set the title of each view, and the `UINavigationController` takes care of the back button labels for you

Comment: ah now I see.  You want to set it like this:

http://pessoal.org/blog/2009/02/03/iphone-sdk-customizing-back-button-title/